# sitefinity 10 upgrade - Chrome not allowing edit of Content blocks

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, sitefinity, sitefinity-feather

I recently upgraded Sitefinity from 9 to 10.  After the upgrade I am not able to edit the content of content blocks on the pages.  This only happens with Chrome.  Everything seems to work just fine in IE and FireFox.  After clicking "Edit" on any of the Content type controls (Content block, image, video, ect) the white loading box shows and then just goes to an all white window the the x to close it out. Any of our custom widgets work fine.  There are no Javascript errors showing in the console. Has anyone seen this type of behavior and how is it fixable?

** Note ** The MVC Content types do seem to work.  It appears that it's just the regular Content types that do not seem to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you zoomed in or out your Chrome browser? 
I've seen this issue with Chrome and WebForms widget designers.
Just try to zoom in and out the browser while the widget designer is open - you should start seeing the contents of the designer.

Comment: OMG are you freaking kidding me.. that worked.  What the hell?? So is there any actual fix for this issue?  I actually noticed it wasn't the upgrade from 9 to 10.  Chrome had recently updated and this was happening in our version 9 instance of Sitefinity.

Comment: I would try this using one of the built-in templates with the Basic theme, or No Theme. If it works fine, then it must be some custom css rules that is breaking it.